# Дополнительные поля Active Directrory C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Всем привет, есть ли возможность при создание нового пользователя в АД, задать ему поле office? Все нужные мне поля, кроме этого есть в UserPrincipal. Он намного удобнее чем DirectoryEntry, хотел бы спросить у тех кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой как ее решить? Делал расширенный класс где через ExtensionSet устанавливал значение для physicalDeliveryOfficeName ( именно так называется атрибут, если задавать через проперти директриэнтри), но почему то метод Сейв вызывал ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста решить, через DirectoryEntry все работает.

код

```
using (PrincipalContext PC = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "165.1.5.25",
"OU=Test,OU=Users,OU=Domain,dc=test,dc=dom", Environment.UserName, "admintest"))
        {
            using (UserPrincipal UsrP = new UserPrincipal(PC))
                try
                {
                    UsrP.Name = "testuser";
                    UsrP.SamAccountName = "testuser";
                    UsrP.GivenName = "Test";
                    UsrP.UserCannotChangePassword = false;
                    UsrP.PasswordNeverExpires = true;
                    UsrP.SetPassword("Qwerty123");
                    UsrP.Enabled = true;
                    UsrP.Description = "000";
                    UsrP.EmailAddress = "testuser@test.ru";
                    UsrP.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "2222";
                    UsrP.Surname = "User";
                    UsrP.DisplayName = "Test User";
                    UsrP.UserPrincipalName = "testuser@gfx.dom";
                    UsrP.Save();

                    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, "testuser");
                    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "TEST_GROUP");
                    group.Members.Add(user);
                    group.Save();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _Log(ex.Message);
                }

        }
```

данный код создает все без ошибки, но стоит изменить класс на UserPrincipalEx, вылетает System.InvalidOperationException: "Сервер не склонен обработать запрос.
Сам класс

```
 [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
    public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
    {
        public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
        { }

        public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                             string samAccountName,
                             string password,
                             bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
        { }

        [DirectoryProperty("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")]
        public string Office
        {
            get
            {
                if (ExtensionGet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").Length != 1)
                    return string.Empty;

                return (string)ExtensionGet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")[0];
            }
            set { ExtensionSet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName", value); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: вы просите совета по коду, но не показываете кода. Вы просите помощи с ошибкой, но на показываете текст ошибки.

Comment: Извиняюсь, добавил код

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был куда проще, в МС12 пользователь называется user, а не person и изменив наследуемый класс [DirectoryObjectClass("Person")] на [DirectoryObjectClass("User")] я решил свою проблему, спасибо кто пытался помочь. Надеюсь мой ответ поможет избежать таких ошибок)

Comment: что такое МС12 ?

Comment: @4per вероятно это Windows Server 2012

Comment: Причина немного другая. Да решение верное, но если вы посмотрите список атрибутов класса [User](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/c-user), то увидите, что интересующий вас атрибут был в нем с самого начала (Win 2k). Так что вы просто использовали неверный класс, независимо от версии схемы AD. В любом случае хорошо что смогли разобраться.